# Is it possible to pass a function to Puppeteer's page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to parse a webpage and can't find a definitive answer to my question.

I am trying to pass a function as an argument to `page.evaluate()`  An object is OK to pass but can't seem to pass a function. Here's a contrived example:

```
const obj = {
 thing: 'thing1',
};

const myfunction = () => {
 return `great ${stuff}`;
};

await page.evaluate((obj, function)=>{
 const thing = myfunction;
},(obj, function));
```

Is it possible to pass a function as an argument to puppeteers page.evaluate()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot pass functions like that. The passed data needs to be serializable via [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), which is not possible for functions.

**Alternative: Expose the function**

To use a function from your Node.js environment inside the page, you need to expose it via [`page.exposeFunction`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction). When called the function is executed inside your Node.js environment

```js
await page.exposeFunction('myfunction', text => `great ${text}`);
await page.evaluate(async (object) => {
  return await window.myfunction(object); // 'great example'
}, 'example');
```

**Alternative: Define the function inside `page.evaluate`**

To use a function inside the page context, you can either define it inside of the context. This way, the function does not have access to your Node.js variables.

```js
await page.evaluate((obj) => {
  const myfunction = (stuff) => `great ${stuff}`;
  return myfunction(obj); // 'great example'
}, 'example');
```

Comment: Hey! Have just tried to Expose the function but I'm now getting ```"Uncaught (in promise) Error: this._pageBindings.get(...) is not a function", source:  (2)```

Comment: 'great example' haha, I thought that was part of the answer. like "yeah this answer is a great example".

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher The "great" came from the question and I just went with it ;)