# How can I evaluate a page retrieved by an url form a parent page in puppeteer`s evaluate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Refering to [Stackquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040196/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-function-to-puppeteers-page-evaluate) I have a second page evaluation in that first evaluation:
like this:

```
        await page.evaluate((obj) => {
        const myfunction = (url) => 
             {
             const browser2 = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
             const page2 = await browser2.newPage();
             await page2.goto(url);
             .... //eval this page 
             return url.concat("testval");
             };
          }, 'example');
```

and now I get the error that the call await browser2 can only be in async function. But I this does not not either:

```
        await page.evaluate((obj) => {
        const async myfunction = (url) => 
             {
             const browser2 = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
             const page2 = await browser2.newPage();
             await page2.goto(url);
             .... //eval this page 
             return url.concat("testval");
             };
          }, 'example');
```

Error: `SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`

How can I open a second page from an url in the first page?

Thanks
Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is invalid. It should be:

```js
const myfunction = async (url) => {};
```