# Javascript Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am writing a JavaScript code:

```
export const isURLImageAccessible = async (url) => {
  // Some code
};

export const getImage = async (page, url) => {
  const img = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const ogImgEl = document.querySelector("meta[property='og:image']");
    const ogImg = ogImgEl?.getAttribute("content");
    if (ogImg != null && (await isURLImageAccessible(ogImg))) {
      return ogImg;
    }

    // Some more code
```

When I am calling the function it throws the following error:

> Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: isURLImageAccessible is not defined

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040978/7325558

Comment: It worked, thanks for the link!

Comment: Yeah it's the same question as pointed out by @SamadRahimi