# Puppeteer - variable not getting passed in the evaluate function

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, async.js, evaluate

I have a function where i am trying to get all the text on the child elements from the parent node.

```
getTextsForChildElements: async function (selector) {
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
        return tds.map(td => td.textContent)
    },selector);
    console.log(data);
},
```

However,  I am seeing `selector is not defined`error.

Tried using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate) as help, but didn't resolve. any idea, how i can pass the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous function which is the first argument to the `page.evaluate` should accept the arguments which you are passing. Right not, it it not taking any arguments. Modify it as below:

```js
getTextsForChildElements: async function (selector) {
    const data = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
        const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
        return tds.map(td => td.textContent)
    },selector);
    console.log(data);
},
```

Comment: thanks @yeniv.. this helped and i was able to get it work