# Evaluate function in puppeteer script not executing during run time

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've run into a situation that I do not understand.  I am using the evaluate function to return links within a drop down in our application.  I pass in an variable array that I would like to use to retrieve links  from these sections in a drop down.
The evaluate function does not run when called.  I do not understand why this is happening.

Here is my code and any help would be appreciated.

```
const selectAccount = await page.evaluate((depositAndCreditAccountIdentifier) => {
        console.log(`depositAndCreditAccountIdentifier ${depositAndCreditAccountIdentifier}`);
        var returnLinks = [];
        for(dn in depositAndCreditAccountIdentifier){
            sectionIdentifier = depositAndCreditAccountIdentifier[dn];
            var varContainer = $('div[ng-if="' + sectionIdentifier + '"]>div[class="multiselect-collection"]>a');
            returnLinks.push(varContainer);
            varContainer.each(function(elementIndex){
                returnLinks.push(varContainer[elementIndex].getAttribute('data-test'));
            });
        }
        console.log(`returnLinks ${returnLinks}`);
        return returnLinks;
    }, depositAndCreditAccountIdentifier);

    console.log(`selectAccount: ${selectAccount}`);
```

Okay,

I have found that it does execute the code logs the information in the browser console.  Thanks to this question: [Puppeteer: pass variable in .evaluate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate)

And it seems my issue is the same.  The *return* does not have anything in it based on this `console.log('returnLinks ${returnLinks}');`.

I tried a different approach to this.  I am returning a Promise() which again everything is gathered that I am looking for but nothing is being returned.

```
exports.returnLinks = async function(page, sectionIdentifier) {
    console.log(`sectionIdentifier: ${sectionIdentifier}`);
    await page.evaluate(async (sectionIdentifier) => {
        function grabAccountAttributes(sectionIdentifier){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
                var returnLinks = [];
                var varContainer = $('div[ng-if="' + sectionIdentifier + '"]>div[class="multiselect-collection"]>a');
                console.log(`varContainer: ${varContainer}`);
                varContainer.each(function(elementIndex){
                    var linkItem = varContainer[elementIndex].getAttribute('data-test');
                    console.log(`linkItem: ${linkItem}`);
                    returnLinks.push(linkItem);
                });
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    resolve(true)
                }, 3000);
            });
        }
        var linksAttributes = await grabAccountAttributes(sectionIdentifier);
        // console.log(`returnLinks ${returnLinks}`);
        return linksAttributes;
    }, sectionIdentifier);
```

Comment: `grabAccountAttributes` resolves to true, you're not returning the returnLinks. plus you don't need a promise here. what do you mean return does not have anything in it? is it undefined or empty array?

Comment: @mbit  In my first example *selectAccount* returns undefined.

Comment: make sure returnLinks is [serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description),  `page.evaluate` resolves to undefined if it's not

Comment: @mbit,  I do not believe it is serializable. I added *JSON.stringify* to the call to the function and it returned as *undefined*.  I am still getting back into JS so I maybe do this wrong.   *txt = JSON.stringify(await getPageContent.returnLinks(page, depositAndCreditAccountIdentifier[i]));*

Comment: if it is not serializable, you can rather rewrite the function and do it in the puppeteer context using `page.$()`. you can also try `page.evaluateHandle` instead of `page.evaluate` as it returns in-page objects.