# Template literal not working on query selector

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am looping through a drop down list and I am trying to select individual options. If I try to use a template literal, the querySelector returns null.

Here are two different queries, one with a template literal and one without. I am using back ticks and everything is the same but the first query returns null while the second one returns the right value even though "i" = 2 in this case.

```
const value = await self.page.evaluate(() => {
              return document.querySelector(`select option:nth-child(${i})`);
});

const value1 = await self.page.evaluate(() => {
              return document.querySelector(`select option:nth-child(2)`);           
});

// Structure
for (let i = 2; i < options.length; i++){

    if (options[i]....){
        const value = await self.page.evaluate((i) => {
             return document.querySelector(`select option:nth-child(${i})`);
            });

    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: what is `typeof i` and what does `console.log(\`select option:nth-child(${i})\`)` print?

Comment: @kaleidawave it says i is of type number, and it prints out "select option:nth-child(2)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linked: [Puppeteer: pass variable in .evaluate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate)

You have to pass another argument to `page.evaluate` to ensure `i` is in the scope

```js
const value = await self.page.evaluate((i) => {
    return document.querySelector(`select option:nth-child(${i})`);
}, i);
```

Comment: Ah that was dumb of me. This one worked, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are passing the function as an argument, the variable `i` will be out of scope when the function is called. You should pass the value when you are defining the function:

```
const value = await self.page.evaluate((i) => {
    return document.querySelector(`select option:nth-child(${i})`);
});
```

Comment: I tried that as well but i is undefined, I edited in the structure of my code but it is most likely a scope issue. Will look into it

Comment: It looks like you're doing that in the looping code that you added in your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, it looks like you've chosen a long way around.

If your intention was to extract `<option>`'s text values into array, you could make use of [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
const [,...options] = [...document.querySelectorAll('select option')].map(option => option.textContent)

console.log(options)
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option>first option</option>
  <option>second option</option>
  <option>last option</option>
</select>
```

*p.s.* if `value` of each option is needed, you may simply replace `.textContent` with `.value`, if DOM nodes themselves, just skip `map()`-part