# Puppeteer identifier string variable won't parse; Unsure why

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to have a string be used inside a puppeteer string, it won't work for some reason.

Specifically with this code

```
await page.waitForSelector('div[class = "sh-dlr__list-result"')
```

When i try to parse in a variable

```
let identified1 = 'div[class = "sh-dlr__list-result"'
```

so making

```
await page.waitForSelector(identified1)
```

It won't work. This is really limiting, is there a way around this issue?

This is the expanded code

https://jsfiddle.net/hewlbern/6p7kdozt/10/
Run it in your computer, jsfiddle unsure if I can run it from there.

I believe it is creating a cors error now - very weird! Why would using a variable create a cors error : /

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it works when you do it without the variable?

Comment: yes - may be something to do with puppeteer

Comment: That's impossible, could you share the rest of your code and where exactly are you declaring that variable so we can see what is happening? You can also just for sanity check log the value of `identified1 ` just before `await page.waitForSelector(identified1)`

Comment: Good idea! I'll list rest of code :)

Comment: @LuísRamalho Yeah would appreciate your help on this one :) Can you see the jsfiddle?

Comment: Since your selector is missing the closing `]` in both cases, I'd be very surprised if either worked

Comment: the closing ] isn't needed actually, but i can close it regardless. the console is calling the string. I believe it's a cors issue now?

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense - why would making it a const bring about a cors issue

Comment: I've ran your code (https://gist.github.com/luisramalho/c04a4b656a44acf65c298e2ac5d553c1) on https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/ and it worked fine :) -- got an array of `{"Product":"Premium Nature Pure Aloe Vera Gel 12 oz 4 oz","Price":"$7.99."}`

Comment: Query blue light glasses, it has separate identifiers. When I use a if statement for changing the identifiers it breaks with cors error

Comment: @LuísRamalho did you manage to see if the other query worked?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @MichaelHolborn, do you ming creating a gist that I can try on try-puppeteer.appspot.com? Thank you!

Comment: gah! let me put it in the jsfiddle :P

Comment: @LuísRamalho does that make more sense?

Comment: Hey @MichaelHolborn, I think I found the cause of the issue and you were right. It didn't work because the code was inside the `page.evaluate()`. I left an answer explaining my findings, I hope you can test it out. It seems to work now in https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you're declaring `identified` inside the `page.evaluate()`. So, when you do the following it's already out of scope.

```
if (currentPage < pagesToScrape) {
  console.log(identified1);
  await Promise.all([
    await page.click(buttonSelector),
    await page.waitForSelector(identified),
  ]);
}
```

You did log the `identified1` but you're using `identified` for the selector.

You'll have to pass the `identifier2` to the `pageFunction` like so:

```
let newProducts = await page.evaluate(({ identifier2 }) => {
  // ...
},{ identifier2 });
```

[See here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) some examples:

Comment: Awesome. If i wanted to do the logic operator to get the correct identifier, regardless of query (so it works it out itself), how would I test it without it being inside a page.evaluate?

Comment: Updated the example again to better explain. Essentially, I want to allow for different types of selectors, and be able to parse in the correct selector. :)

Comment: It's hard to help you further, the jsfiddle is not working and I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. I think the key takeaway is that if you want to use a variable inside the `page.evaluate()` you'll have to pass it to the `pageFunction`. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate) is helpful.

Comment: thanks for answering. If possible, take down the gist. Cheers!