# how can I pass variable to the page in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

for example I have a  variable called link , I want to get the value of that variable after exucuting a page.goto() in puppeteer .

this is example code

```
//this is my link variable 
const link = "something";
 (async() => {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless: false,
                //args: ['--proxy-server=161.129.155.43:3128']
                timeout: 20000
            });
            browser.userAgent(browsers[0]);
            const page = await browser.newPage();

//called variable before goto() 
      console.log(link) //=>something

            await page.goto(url);

//called variable after goto() 
      console.log(link) //=>undefined

            await page.evaluate(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName("sA5rQ")[0].click();
                       }, 3000);
    })
            setTimeout(async() => {
                await browser.close();
            }, 60000);
        })();
```

as you see in comments inside my code the value after executing page.goto() are undefined and I can only use variables from that page in browser by reading and scraping data .

how can I pass the link variable inside the pupputeer browser page?

Comment: I can't see why your example would work like that. Consider posting your exact code instead.

Comment: this is the full code inside an api function for posting data , `app.post('/',(req,res)=>{//code}`

Comment: I have tried many times , I think when it runs the url all variables should be something inside the browser page and I can just controle what I have inside new browser page

Comment: In the code above, you're logging `link` inside your NodeJS program, not inside of the browser/puppeteer.

Comment: for example I want to set `document.getelementById('input').value=link`  ,how can I let it be passed to the document element's value in browser?

Comment: That's another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate

Comment: yes , it is , it s what I m looking for exactly , thank you.