# detect changes in DOM with puppeteer _ MutationObserver is working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, mutation-observers

I wrote a function based on MutationObServer :

```
module.exports.crawler = async(page, link)=>{
    try {
        await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
        await page.waitForSelector('#dbp')
        await page.waitForTimeout(10000)
        await page.exposeFunction('puppeteerLogMutation', () => {
          console.log('Mutation Detected: A child node has been added or removed.');
        });
        
      
        tables = await page.evaluate(async()=>{
          target = document.querySelector("#d02");
          const observer = new MutationObserver( mutations => {
            console.log(mutations)
          });
          observer.observe(target, { childList: true });
         
          return data
        })
    console.log(tables)
    await page.close()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

target variable is changing every 20 seconds . I want to detect the changes . but this is not working.any idea?

Comment: I'm assuming that `tables` is undefined?

Comment: @evolutionxbox table is correct I can capture the data . but problem is i cannot detect the dom changes

Comment: Maybe this question may help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/puppeteer-pass-variable-in-evaluate - try passing a function into evaluate that gets called inside the mutation observer?

Comment: `console.log(mutations)` is logged to browser console. You need to call exposed function instead there like `window.puppeteerLogMutation()`.