# puppeteer: How to loop through nth-child and do something based on a condition?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Inside every **tr** I want to get the date from **td:nth-child(2)** and compare it with today's date. If they are equal I want to click **td:nth-child(5)** . I want to do the same process for several   **tr**.
I tried to use loop but I received errors like
**>Error: ... 'tbody > tr:nth-child(undefined) > td:nth-child(2)' is not a valid selector. OR >ReferenceError: i is not defined**

Can anyone help me with this please?

```
 

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const date = document.querySelector('tbody > tr:nth-child('+i+') > td:nth-child(2)').innerText;
    return date;
  });
  if (data === today) {
    await page.click('tbody > tr:nth-child('+i+') > td:nth-child(5)');
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` variable is not available inside `evaluate` function.

You need to pass it as an `pageFunction` argument.

```
const data = await page.evaluate((i) => {
    const date = document.querySelector('tbody > tr:nth-child('+i+') > td:nth-child(2)').innerText;
    return date;
  }, i);
```

[`page.evaluate` documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

See also [How can I pass variable into an evaluate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/how-can-i-pass-variable-into-an-evaluate-function)