# is it possible to edit an href in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I would like my puppeteer to change an element that redirects to a certain page to instead - redirect to a different one. is that possible?

Example, the element is:

```
<a href="https://old.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/18cg1ul/serious_teachers_what_is_the_worst_thing_youve/" data-event-action="comments" class="bylink comments may-blank" rel="nofollow">323 comments</a>
```

I want it to be:

```
<a href="https://google.com" data-event-action="comments" class="bylink comments may-blank" rel="nofollow">323 comments</a>
```

Comment: I'm [not sure what the point of this is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676), but sure, this is possible. Have you tried writing code at all? Select the element and set its `.href` property: `await page.$eval('[href*="serious_teachers"]', el => el.href = "https://www.google.com")`. If you want to go to a page, though, just go to it directly: `await page.goto(wherever)`. Changing the href doesn't change it for anyone but yourself, it's not hacking Reddit or anything like that, and changing it just to click on it yourself doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ggorlen Hi, the point is Reddit doesn't register the upvotes unless it comes from a click within the site itself, for some reason.

                            await page.$eval('a[href="https://old.reddit.com/r/LSD/comments/18t1rp7/do_you_think_of_acid_as_the_king_drug/"]', el => el.href = link13132)

How would I send the link13132 variable to this function so I can use it?

Comment: [How can I pass variable into an evaluate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/how-can-i-pass-variable-into-an-evaluate-function)