# Edit an href in a site

Tags: node.js, function, puppeteer

so I've been using puppeteer and trying to edit an href

```
await page.$eval('a[href="https://old.reddit.com/r/LSD/comments/18t1rp7/do_you_think_of_acid_as_the_king_drug/"]', el => el.href = link)
```

for some reason I cannot pass the link variable to this function, how do I do it?

Comment: Funny? I was trying to understand if that resolves your problem or it's a another issue. Where did I imply humor :D?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass variable into an evaluate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/how-can-i-pass-variable-into-an-evaluate-function)

Comment: Pretty much a repost of [is it possible to edit an href in puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617866/is-it-possible-to-edit-an-href-in-puppeteer?noredirect=1#comment137039553_77617866)

Answer (score 0):

You've just discovered one of the big limitations of puppeteer. Stuff in the node context cannot be used in the context of functions evaluated within the page. Fortunately, Puppeteer provides the ability to pass arguments ([read the docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page._eval) to play around this limitation. The following code should work iirc:

```
await page.$eval(
'a[href="https://old.reddit.com/r/LSD/comments/18t1rp7/do_you_think_of_acid_as_the_king_drug/"]',
(el, link) => el.href = link,
THE_URL_TO_RUN_WITH
)
```